# How can I change this spacing?

Tags: spacing, floats

How can I change this spacing between text and table?

[image: spacing]

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) While I strongly suspect that some user here might be able to read minds `:-)`, unfortunately most of us can't, and we actually need to look at some code. Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, possibly starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing.

Comment: The picture is placed at the very top, the table at the very bottom. \raggedbottom could be a try with global consequences.

Answer (score 1):

My first answer!
Sorry, I have not seen any attachment, maybe you can tell me how to find it.

As for this question, `\vspace` can meet your requirements, my code is like this:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{table}[H]
\vspace{-0.5 cm}
\caption{This is caption}\label{table1}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        speed & 15000 & 20000\\
        speed & 28138 & 25463
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

But also, the floating format influences the spacing between paragraphs, please check your context.

Comment: Awesome that you're making answers! Just a pointer: The OP (and future TeX-ers with this problem) probably would find it better if the code you provide is actually runnable out of the box. E.g. it should have a `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`/`\end{document}` in addition to the you  use (which you have added here).